# Angular another component's nativeelement is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, components

ı have two component .one of them is ModalComponent that uses inside another component.

ModalComponent

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css'],
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() name: string;
  @ViewChild('close') public closeModal: ElementRef;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  close() {

this.closeNodal.nativeElement.click()
  }
}
```

modal.component.html

```
<div
class="modal"
[id]="name"
tabindex="-1"
role="dialog"
aria-labelledby="defModalHead"
aria-hidden="true"
>
<div class="modal-backdrop in"></div>
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" #close class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span
        ><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
      </button>
      <h2 class="modal-title success">{{title}}</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-danger">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

HomeComponent.html

```
<app-modal name="personAdd" title="Person Add Form">
  <P>FORM ELEMENTS </P>

  <button>Add</button>
</app-modal>
```

homeComponent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit  {
  @ViewChild('ModalComponent') modalComponent: ModalComponent;

  constructor(
   
  ) {}


  ngOnInit(): void {
   
  }


  PersonMovementAdd() {
    this.modalComponent.close()

  }
 



}
```

when ı click add button ı want to reach modalcomponent's close() method but ı take undefined error.How can ı reach modalcomponent's close() method from homecomponent

Comment: console.log(this.modalComponent) ... is it defined? what's the output? it sounds like modalComponent is not defined so, of course, you can't call its close method ... it will prob work once modalComponent is defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
@ViewChild(ModalComponent) modalComponent: ModalComponent;
```

instead of:

```
@ViewChild('ModalComponent') modalComponent: ModalComponent;
```

Comment: this.closeNodal.nativeElement.click() should be this.closeModal.nativeElement.click()